# Rewrite is not working after application pool is stopped

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, load-balancing

There are 2 web applications under the default website.
**CSM_BETA, CSM_RELEASE**
[image]

The content of those 2 is both the same.

My final goal is as below:

1. Stop one of the 2 application pools(for example:CSM_RELEASE), and keep the other one working. The reason is that, I need to update something in CSM_RELEASE and the application pool needs to be stop.
2. At the same time, when users access CSM_RELEASE, the site actually redirects them to CSM_BETA(using IIS7 rewrite). That makes users be able to continue access the site instead of waiting for the application pool to be restarted.

However, the current condition is that, **when I stop the application pool of CSM_RELEASE, the url rewrite is not working any more. Users always get a 503 error instead of being redirected to CSM_BETA**.

I am not sure why this happens and how could I achieve my goal.

Any suggestion will be appreciated! :)